# DevExpress WPF grid bound to List<String> using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, grid, devexpress

I am trying to do something that should be simple, but think I am just not seeing the answer.

I have a List with several strings.

I would like to bind it to a DevExpress DXGrid.

It appears that the grid is showing the correct number of row, but not displaying my text.

I am using the MVVm patern and have seperated my ViewModel and View.

Thanks for the help.

Here is the XAML code:

```
     <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="0" DataSource="{Binding Path=ErrorLog}"  >
          <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Error Log" AllowEditing="False" />
          </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
          <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView  NewItemRowPosition="None" />
          </dxg:GridControl.View>
     </dxg:GridControl>
```

Here is the View Model Code:

```
private List<string> _errorLog;
public List<string> ErrorLog
{
  get { return _errorLog; }
  set
  {
    _errorLog = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("ErrorLog");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what the column should display, so it's not displaying anything...

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Error Log" AllowEditing="False" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" />
```

(note that there is not path for the binding: the column is bound to the string itself, not a member of the string)

Comment: Hi Thomas, that's where i went off the reservation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

that doesn't work.. use this instead

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Value">
   <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
    <Binding Path="RowData.Row"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

GridColumn.DisplayMemberBinding is now marked as obsolete. It is suggested that the Binding property should be used instead.

```
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding RowData.Row}">
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

[ColumnBase.DisplayMemberBinding Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/DevExpressXpfGridColumnBase_DisplayMemberBindingtopic)